# I want to fire another kind of exception in this case. PHP

Tags: php, exception

When I try to connect with the Redis server with this code I haven't any problem testing if the server is UP. The problem is when the server is DOWN. In that case I solved this escenario with the classic Try/catch. My problem is that I'd like to manage this exception with "my_custom_exception" class, which has more useful functions, instead of the class Exception. Is there anyway of making this?. I know how to extend the class Exception, but in this case is a library of third parts.

```
function show_status_redis_server(){
    try{
        $redis = RedisDB::fetch_instance();//this ...........................
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Redis server is down"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (my_custom_exception $e)`

Comment: but in that case I need to throw inside the library with: throw new custom_exception(......), no?. I'm trying

Comment: It depends on how you want to do it. If you want to just catch it and handle it where you have the echo, you can do what I have above. If you want to handle the exception elsewhere, then you will need to re-throw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mike says in his comment it depends on where you want to make use of the functionality. The easiest thing is going to be to handle it in the code using the class:

```
function show_status_redis_server(){
    try{
        $redis = RedisDB::fetch_instance();//this ...........................
    }catch(Exception $e){
        throw MyRedisException::createFromException($e); 

    }
}
```

or

```
function show_status_redis_server(){
    try{
        $redis = RedisDB::fetch_instance();//this ...........................
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $re = MyRedisException::createFromException($e);
        // do stuff with $re here 

    }
}
```

Beynond that i can think of two ways... make a wrapper library that use the redis lib you are using but serves as an intermidary - this way you can catch the generic exceptions in your libraries classes and then throw whatever you want.

Second way would be to just do a custom error handler that catches uncaught exceptions - inspects them for redis somehow, and then rethrows custom exceptions. However at that point you have to let the exceptions fall through until the end of execution which doesnt give you many options for handling them unless its just to format and output messages.

Comment: You are aware that you have to write the `creatFromException` method, correct? I just used that as an example.

Comment: yes, my problem is that I dont know how to handle the object $e, I saw in the documentation, but I saw only constructors with "message", code, and previous exception, is it previous exception?

Comment: Yes i would do it as previous exception.